# How to detect height of textbox on keydown event once the text is removed in WPF Application

Tags: wpf

I am new to wpf.

In my application, there is text box. A paragraph text is set programmatically.

What I want to achieve is, when a user presses enter in the textbox, the text box should become blank and I want to show the actual height of the textbox(after deletion of the text in the textbox).

Note: After I run the application, the textbox displays the paragraph which was set programmatically. At this moment, the actual height of the textbox is 168. Once I press enter, the text is removed but it shows the actual height of the text box 168. It should display 15.

Please guide me.

My Code:

```
 private void OnKeyDownHandler(object sender, KeyEventArgs e)
        {

            var tb = sender as TextBox;
            if(e.key==key.Enter){
tb.Text="";
Messagebox.Show(tb.ActualHeight);
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved the issue. If any one come across same, it might help.

Keydown event is triggered only in the case of key down.

In my case, upon pressing enter key, textbox becomes blank and its height is set back to default height (14) but at this moment, the actual height is 168. To know the actual height of the textbox, I need to press the key down again. In second time, it shows the right actual height of the text box.